# Should I use the 'noreferrer' attribute on my website links (to open in a new window) as a safety measure?

Tags: javascript, links, malicious

There are many sites on the internet that recommend you to add the `noopener noreferrer` attributes to your link as a safety measure. This is to avoid malicious scripts from other domains to take control of your window (for a link with `target="_blank"`).

There's even an `eslint` rule to make sure of that:

https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-target-blank.md`

https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/

**QUESTION**

I get the `noopener` part. It makes sense. But do I really need the `noreferrer` to be safe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to use one or the other.  From [Google tools for web developers -- Links to cross-origin destinations are unsafe](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/noopener):

> - `rel="noopener"` prevents the new page from being able to access the `window.opener` property and ensures it runs in a separate process.
> - `rel="noreferrer`" attribute has the same effect, but also prevents the `Referer` header from being sent to the new page.

So there is no need to use both of them.   Either of them will prevent the security problem on its own.